# English vocabulary by levels

Tags: data-request, english, dictionary

(Duplicated from /r/datasets https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/5iozdt/request_english_vocabulary_by_levels/)

My group is doing a data mining assignment in which we want to categorize english learning videos based on the words appearing,  assigning them levels of difficulty.

We have found a list of english words organized by level for chinese speakers that are learning Chinese in high school in Taiwan. This list consists of around ~6700 words from level 1 to level 6.

This quantity is however too small for the words of the videos we are analyzing, getting around only 30% of the words appearing on the videos.

Does anyone know of a bigger dataset for english words organized by level? (containing more words per level or even more levels).

I know there are lists of more common words in English, but we would like something with labels, maybe from some standardized test.

Comment: If all else fails, you can [assign the levels yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141092/determine-the-difficulty-of-an-english-word)

Comment: Did you [search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=english+words+difficulty+levels) enough? I found both links in my comments within 30 seconds.

Comment: @JanDoggen I haven't seen that question. And I have searched enough. We have two datasets. One of >6700 words and one of >12000 words, both classified by level. Not enough though. I will delete this question because it is a duplicate, but still no answer.

Comment: You don't have to delete it. Questions marked as duplicate serve as pointers to the 'original'. Depending on how people search they could find the pointed-to duplicate via your question.